# Oracle group by minutes in date column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

If I have the following table :

```
ID                       d_date                        d_value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 1/16/2018 03:41:01 PM                 10   
2                 1/16/2018 03:41:02 PM                 20 
3                 1/16/2018 03:41:03 PM                 30 
4                 1/16/2018 03:44:04 PM                 40 
5                 1/16/2018 03:44:05 PM                 50 
6                 1/16/2018 03:46:06 PM                 60 
7                 1/17/2018 03:41:01 PM                 70 
8                 1/17/2018 03:41:02 PM                 80 
9                 1/17/2018 03:44:03 PM                 90 
10                1/17/2018 03:45:04 PM                 100
```

And need to get the value for the last second of each minute. So for the previous table, results are the following :

```
ID                       d_date                        value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
3                 1/16/2018 03:41:03 PM                 30 
5                 1/16/2018 03:44:05 PM                 50 
6                 1/16/2018 03:46:06 PM                 60 
8                 1/17/2018 03:41:02 PM                 80 
9                 1/17/2018 03:44:03 PM                 90 
10                1/17/2018 03:45:04 PM                 100
```

I had to use inner join to achieve it :

```
select dt, mx, d_tb.d_value from (
    select to_char(d_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') dt, max(d_date) mx from d_table
    group by to_char(d_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
) d_sub
left outer join d_table d_tb on d_tb.d_date = d_sub.mx
order by dt
```

The issue that there are thousands of records in the table, is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by to_char(d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                                order by d_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from d_table d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

For performance, you can start with an index on `(to_char(d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), d_date)`.  You can also try the following (using the same index:

```
select d.*
from d_table d
where d.d_date = (select max(d2.d_date)
                  from d_table d2
                  where to_char(d2.d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(d.d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                 );
```

In either case, the key to performance is a function-based index to extract the minute.

As Boneist suggests, `trunc(d_date, 'MI')` is a probably better than converting to a date.

Comment: It takes more time than the the inner join, any idea ?

Comment: @BilalHalayqa . . . The two do different things.  Yours does not take the date into account, so it should be returning many fewer rows.

Comment: `trunc(d_date)` would be better than to_char, IMHO; keeps the datatype the same for a start.

Comment: @Boneist . . . Actually, I agree.  I just used `to_char()` because the OP used that.

Comment: Using trunc(d_date, 'MI') will ignore hours, days and years.

Comment: @BilalHalayqa . . . When I run `trunc(x, 'MI')` it includes hours, day, months, and years (as well as the minute).  I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is with [`keep .. dense_rank` with `first` or `last`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html), which doesn't require an additional index:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by d_date) as id,
  max(d_date) as d_date,
  max(d_value) keep (dense_rank last order by d_value) as d_value
from d_table
group by trunc(d_date, 'MI');

        ID D_DATE                 D_VALUE
---------- ------------------- ----------
         3 2018-01-16 15:41:03         30
         5 2018-01-16 15:44:05         50
         6 2018-01-16 15:46:06         60
         8 2018-01-17 15:41:02         80
         9 2018-01-17 15:44:03         90
        10 2018-01-17 15:45:04        100
```

If it's possible to have two values in the same second then you'll need to decide how to break the tie - i.e. decide which to use - and modify the `order by` appropriately.

The [`trunc(d_date, 'MI')`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) strips the second from the date value so you group by the minute value; and you need a normal aggregate `max(d_date)` to get the highest actual value in each group.

Comment: Using trunc(d_date, 'MI') will ignore hours, days and years

Comment: @BilalHalayqa - no it won't. The results in my answer would be very different if it behaved like that. (I'd wondered if you'd confused MI with MM, but that doesn't ignore years). Check the docs, or try `select sysdate, trunc(sysdate, 'MI') from dual;` which will give something like `2018-01-18 09:24:31 2018-01-18 09:24:00`.